# x*x vs Math.pow(x,2) java performance

Tags: java, performance

I have done some testing about whether `x*x` or `Math.pow(x, 2)` is faster in Java. I was expecting simple `x*x` to be somewhat faster, however, it turned out that its about equally fast. Can someone enlighten me, how is that possible, please?

Comment: How exactly did you test this? Writing micro-benchmarks is much harder than you think: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: why dont you try `x*x*x*x` vs `Math.pow(x,4)`, you might get the answer

Comment: I tested it by running the same operation in a loop and measuring time by System.currenttimemillis() function

Comment: Yea i tried x*x*x and so on, which is getting faster then function, however, i am interested in this particular situation.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

> how is that possible, please

Because `Math.pow` is JVM intrinsic, that is, JIT-compiler inlines the call. Furthermore, when it sees that exponent is a constant `2`, it replaces the call with exactly `x*x`.

[Proof from HotSpot sources](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/5755b2aee8e8/src/share/vm/opto/library_call.cpp#l1799)

Answer (score 2):

The internal implementation of `Math.pow()` is delegated to a native function so it could be reasonable for a good performance.
In any case to have valid test results you have to test the time in a loop to have an execution time realistic.

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I actualy tested it in a loop with bilion of iterations to get a decent results..

Answer (score -2):

For all you know it's JITted (or even already in compile-time) down to the same exact thing. These kinds of micro-benchmarks rarely give very usable results, since there is no real context.

It's definitely not a reason to prefer one over another, since real world code rarely has a simple `x^2` operation as a performance hotspot.