# Java Math.pow(x,2.0) vs Math.pow(x,2.0000001) performance

Tags: java, performance

I am trying to compare performance of `pow(x,2.0)` and `pow(x,2.0000001)` and I though that `2.0` would be much faster, but they are at the same speed. I even removed JIT optimizations by running jar with `-Xint` parameter.

Any idea why is that, please? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: The implementation is free to spend a conditional branch to test for special case or to implement all cases with the same code. All that matters is the result. There are no guarantees on the execution time. (Not that, if you are not careful, you would see them even if they are there).

Comment: Why do you expect a performance boost? The type of both parameters is `double`.

Comment: Because it's just using one magical implementation that's specialized to all doubles; it's not using any special magic for integer powers.  If you just use multiplication directly (`x * x`) you'll get better results.

Comment: I am expecting better results because source code for Math.pow(x,y) has return condition for y==2, as you can see here
http://developer.classpath.org/doc/java/lang/StrictMath-source.html

Comment: @TomášMocek, perhaps Math.pow (as opposed to StrictMath.pow, which you reference) does not differentiate between exponents?

Comment: That source code is for GNU Classpath.  Are you running with GNU Classpath?  What does `java -version` print?

Comment: thanks for answers guys, java -version prints 1.7.0_51, Java SE Runtime Environment etc, so i guess u are right with GNU Classpath, right? also, thank you s.bandara, when i tried StrictMath.pow() instead of Math.pow(), the result was as expected

Comment: The optimization is again broken in JDK9: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8190869

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In spite of unfair downvotes, the question makes much sense, since it reveals the real JVM bug.

When you run Oracle JDK the performance of `Math.pow(x, 2.0)` highly varies between JVM versions.

- Before JDK 7u40 `Math.pow` used software implementation, i.e. it simply called [__ieee754_pow](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/e_pow.c) function that emulates the operation in software. It was rather slow, but it did have a special case for y == 2.
- Since JDK 7u40 `Math.pow` became a JVM intrinsic that was translated into FPU instructions by the JIT. However, with this optimization the special case has been lost, resulting in a performance regression for y == 2, see [bug JDK-8029302](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8029302).
- This performance regression has been fixed in JDK 8u25 and upcoming 7u80. Since JDK 8u25 `Math.pow` works fast enough for all values, but extremely fast for y == 2. See the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144275/xx-vs-math-powx-2-java-performance).

**P.S.** The approximate times in seconds for 100M invocations of `Math.pow` on my machine with different versions of JDK.

```
             Math.pow(x, 2.0)    Math.pow(x, 2.0000001)
JDK 7u25            3.0                30.4
JDK 7u40           11.1                11.1
JDK 8u40            0.1                11.1
```

Comment: When you say "Java implementation", you actually mean a native method, correct?

Comment: Quote from the linked JDK bug: `Using "-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintIntrinsics" shows the intrinsic implementation is used in both cases.` So the actual change was only in the intrinsic itself, not in the fact that an intrinsic was introduced.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Well, it was a rather stupid intrinsic. I mean it didn't crawl through all [JNI stuff](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24747484/3448419) (in this sense it was an *"intrinsic"*), but it still had to make a native call to the emulation function. In JDK7u40 it became a *"real intrinsic"*, i.e. the implementation was written in assembly and was inlined into the caller. I've updated the answer to be more precise. Thanks for reviewing :)